# link errors while using opencv 2.4.10

Tags: opencv, hyperlink

I am working on OCR project using opencv2.4.10. While executing my code there comes an error `"cannot find or open file calib3d248d.lib"` I am using 2.4.10, why will this arise? I uncheked the check box for using inherent library functions still that error occurs. What do I do to execute this?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you set a wrong library name. "calib3d248d.lib" -> "calib3d2410d.lib".